# Problems with PUT request in react.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, express

I am having problems with this PUT request when I only edit one of the fields then press save all the values apart from the edited one become null. I am fairly certain it has something to do with the `onChange()`, but I am not sure what. I have all the relevant code below. Any ideas?

**Admin.js**

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./admin.css";
import ApiContext from "../../context/ApiContext";

const Admin = () => {
    const {
        onChange,
        retrieveHeaderData,
        submitHeaderData,
        updateHeaderData,
        headerData,
    } = useContext(ApiContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveHeaderData();
    }, []);

    let submitOrUpdateHeaderData = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!headerData) {
            submitHeaderData();
        } else {
            updateHeaderData();
        }
    };

    return (
        <section id="admin">
            <h2>Change user details</h2>
            <div className="container admin__container">
                <div className="admin__forms">
                    <form onSubmit={submitOrUpdateHeaderData}>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="title"
                            placeholder="Title"
                            value={headerData.title}
                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="name"
                            placeholder="Name"
                            value={headerData.name}
                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="linkedIn"
                            placeholder="LinkedIn"
                            value={headerData.linkedIn}
                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="github"
                            placeholder="Github"
                            value={headerData.github}
                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                        />
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                            Save details
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default Admin;
```

**ApiContext.js**

```js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const ApiContext = createContext();

export default ApiContext;

export const ApiProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [headerData, setHeaderData] = useState({});


    const onChange = (e) => {
        setHeaderData((headerData) => ({
            ...headerData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        }));
    };

    let retrieveHeaderData = async () => {
        let response = await fetch("/api/retrieve/header-data", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        let data = await response.json();
        if (response.status === 200) {
            setHeaderData(data[0]);
        }
    }

    let submitHeaderData = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let response = await fetch("/api/submit/header-data", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: headerData.title,
                name: headerData.name,
                linkedIn: headerData.linkedIn,
                github: headerData.github,
            }),
        });
        let data = await response.json();
        if (response.ok) {
            setHeaderData(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    };

    let updateHeaderData = async () => {
        let response = await fetch("/api/update/header-data", {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: headerData.title,
                name: headerData.name,
                linkedIn: headerData.linkedIn,
                github: headerData.github,
            }),
        });
        let data = await response.json();
        if (response.ok) {
            setHeaderData(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    }


    let contextData = {
        headerData: headerData,
        onChange: onChange,
        submitHeaderData: submitHeaderData,
        updateHeaderData: updateHeaderData,
        retrieveHeaderData: retrieveHeaderData
    };

    return (
        <ApiContext.Provider value={contextData}>
            {children}
        </ApiContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**server.js (the PUT request in question)**

```js
app.put("/api/update/header-data", async (req, res) => {
    let data = req.body;

    let updateHeaderQuery =
        "UPDATE header SET name = ?, title = ?, linkedIn = ?, github = ?";

    try {
        await database.query(updateHeaderQuery, [
            data.name,
            data.title,
            data.linkedIn,
            data.github,
        ]);
        console.log("Header Data Updated Successfully !");
        return res.json({
            status: "ok",
            message: "Updated data into header table",
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        res.sendStatus("400").json({
            status: "error",
            message: "Error updating data into header table",
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it was an issue with the `onChange` function. Here is what I changed it to.

```js
const onChange = (e) => {
        setHeaderData((prevData) => ({
            ...prevData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        }));
    };
```

Comment: What was the change you made to `onChange` ?

Comment: The previous onChange had `headerData` not `prevData`. It was just a stupid mistake which I should've noticed immediately